# Set background color of the material chip programmatically

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-chips

```
Chip chip = new Chip(context);
chip.setBackgroundcolor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```

The above line gives the error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Do not set the background resource; Chip manages its own background drawable.
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can set background color of material chip by following line (Kotlin)

```
chip.chipBackgroundColor = getColorStateList(/*your preferred color*/)
```

Comment: the following line worked for me 
     Chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.colorBlue);

Answer (score 32):

For Kotlin, you should use this:

```
chip.chipBackgroundColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourColor))
```

For Java:

```
chip.setChipBackgroundColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourColor)));
```

Comment: its works chip.chipBackgroundColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourColor))
thank u

Answer (score 8):

Use the method [**`setChipBackgroundColorResource`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip#setchipbackgroundcolorresource):

```
chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.chip_selector_color);
```

Otherwise use the method [`setChipBackgroundColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip#setchipbackgroundcolor)

```
chip.setChipBackgroundColor(AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(context, R.color.chip_selector_color));
```

Answer (score 6):

- **Try this:**

> ```
> chip.setChipBackgroundColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.Green));
> ```

Comment: This method is deprecated, please use `chip.setChipBackgroundColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white)));` instead

Answer (score 1):

use backgroundTint in xml

```
            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/timetext_id"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="#39b8db"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Time"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin

`chip.chipBackgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this.context,R.color.**yourcolorid**)`